# VPN Traffic Routing Check

Tags: iptables, ip, routing, vpn

I've been trying to route some traffic through my VPN and the rest directly through my ISP, and I came across this article:

http://www.htpcguides.com/force-torrent-traffic-vpn-split-tunnel-debian-8-ubuntu-16-04/

However, I decided to try my hand and make my own rules. I believe I accomplished what I needed to without using as many rules as the article lists.

I'm hoping to find somebody kind enough to review my rules and let me know if there are any leaks or mistakes. I confirmed that the correct traffic is being routed through the VPN by looking at IP addresses. Here are my rules:

Routing:

```
$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local 
32765:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup 128 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default 


$ ip route show table main
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.129  metric 202 


$ ip route show table 128
default via 10.8.8.249 dev tun0 
10.8.8.249 dev tun0  scope link  src 10.8.8.250 
68.235.53.24 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  scope link
```

Mangle and NAT Tables:

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -L -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2964K packets, 3153M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2964K packets, 3153M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1651K packets, 424M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 917K  203M MARK       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             
owner UID match debian-transmission MARK set 0x1

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1651K packets, 424M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 


$ sudo iptables -t nat -L -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2814 packets, 1123K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2799 packets, 1122K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 18894 packets, 1297K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3327 packets, 299K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
15567  998K MASQUERADE  all  --  any    tun0    anywhere             anywhere
```

IP Checks:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/ip
xxx.xx.xxx.177
$ sudo -u debian-transmission curl ipinfo.io/ip
68.235.53.24
```